# Shifted Hyperlinks in LaTeX PDF

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, cross-referencing, pdf

I've encountered a very annoying problem with hyperlinks. I have a rather large LaTeX file (>400 pages including graphics, tables, TikZ, etc.) that I've cut down to this [MWE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nInihUJTfy5ulVOx9KVjaUuECDAMuV0j/view?usp=share_link).
The bigger I let the file get the more shifted all of the hyperlinks got (incl. the ones in the ToC, which is why I left it in there with only one real entry). I can not really see a pattern when commenting out parts that change the shifts, so that the current state still has two extreme examples:

- the "1st table" link on page 2 has to be clicked in the row above (also see the screenshot, yellow bar is where the link is)
- the "2" link on page 3 is shifted right about a tab length
  with the 2nd example I was able actually see a pattern, which is why I included it twice, though highly irregular. including a formula before the link shifts it more to the right, as well as more regular characters.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- used all kinds of different PDF readers (duh) and pdflatex compilers
- adjusted the hyperlink settings, until I found out that it even does it without any parameters
- cut out all grapics, TikZ, even the tables that the links were to (had to leave something to refer to)
- commented out all unnecessary packages (the ones left in the structure file can of course also be excluded right now, but I need them in the final version; I actually read all the manual over the last days and could not find any interferences)

I'm looking forward to any solutions, tips or just ideas what else I could try. I am really frustrated here, so I would not be surprised if I have overlooked something, working on this problem for over a year throughout my writing.

Thanks in advance!
Cheers,
Chris

[image: yellow bar is where the clickable link is]

Comment: Please don't post links that could break in the future and make the question unusable, and post the MWE here.

Comment: Hi @Miyase thanks for your advice! I could not find a way to post multiple files here. because the MWE is still quite big. how can I do that?

Comment: I have no problems in a current texlive with standard pdflatex.  But you are using a special engine, texpdftex, so ask their support.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you, this actually works with the mwe, but still does not with the original. I'll reach out for my engine's support and keep this thread up to date!

Comment: there seems to be a problem with the hyperref drivers of Texifier, which they are currently fixing. I do not know why the problems remained before with other engines (maybe I did not compile often enough). thanks again for the quick answer!